# How to use Async when call API data?

Tags: reactjs, async.js

This is my source , i loop array include multiply i

```
    import request from 'superagent';
    import waterfall from 'async-es/waterfall';
    import async from 'async-es';
    let total_arr = [];
    for (i = 0; i < range.values.length; i++) {

        self.getDataServiceGoogle( range[i] ,function(response){   

          /// response is an array
             total_arr.push(response);

        });

      }
  }
}
```

Response's value from getDataServiceGoogle each loop is an array . But It's just responsed after about 0.2 , 0.3 second . I want to **total_arr** assemble many arrays . Exp :

```
 total_arr = [
       response_1,
       response_2,
       response_3,
       response_4,
       ..........,
       response_n
   ]
```

I must to **async** with that case ? . Anyone have any solution
help me about that . I nerver use async.
P/s : I write it by reactjs

Comment: If self.getDataServiceGoogle can return a promise, you can create an array of promises for each value of i, then use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Thanks @fzxt. I'll try